# How can I create an offline iphone web app?

Tags: iphone, offline, iphone-web-app, web-applications

I have a mobile web application for my iPhone. My application is in general dynamic so all the files I am using are in php. How can I make this web app working offline? Can I still use the  and include the index.php file there? Or there is another way for dynamic pages?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP files locally. They require a server with PHP capability to evaluate the PHP and render the page.

It is not possible to port a PHP-based web-app to an offline "App Store" app.

Comment: Hello, I am using a server for the PHP. The question is if I can use the manifest tag of HTML 5 for creating a manifest file which will include the index.php